# Domain-Driven Design: Storage layer and MySQL client

Tags: domain-driven-design, go

I'm very new in DDD and I was following one of the videos of GohperCon to structure of my Golang App using DDD with Hexagonal Architecture. At the lowest (deepest) layer is the `storage` that can be Memory, JSON, SQL ...

I'm planning to use MySQL and I structured my `storage` directory as follow:

```
app
|
+- storage
   |
   +- mysql
      |
      +- TABLE_NAME_0
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
      +- TABLE_NAME_1
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
```

I used the MySQL table name as the sub-folder of the `mysql` directory to separate the CRUD for each table.

But now I'm stuck with the MySQL connection. I want to create one connection and use it with both `repository.go`. I'm seeing 2 options (there might be more):

1. Create `clients` directory under the `app` directory and have `mysql.go` to create client.

```
app
|
+- clients
   |
   +- mysql.go
+- storage
   |
   +- mysql
      |
      +- TABLE_NAME_0
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
      +- TABLE_NAME_1
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
```

2. Create `mysql.go` under the `mysql` directory.

```
app
|
+- storage
   |
   +- mysql
      +- mysql.go
      +- TABLE_NAME_0
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
      +- TABLE_NAME_1
         |
         +- model.go
         +- repository.go
```

In either case, `main.go` uses that to create the MySQL client first and then pass it down to each `repository.go`.

I'm not sure which path is the right way or is my thinking and the approach for DDD is correct and I was hoping someone here can help me.

Comment: DDD doesn't prescribe anything regarding source code directory/file structure, so you're basically free to choose as long as you're not mixing up logical layers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the premise that DDD prescribes how to structure software, which is false.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.